# Synchronizing two BindingSources

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, dataset, bindingsource

I have a form with a `DataGridView` that opens a details form on a double click.
When opening the second form I set it to use the same `DataSet` instance as the parent form. i now want to make sure the second form is pointing at the same `DataRow` as the parent as well.
At first I just sent in the `Position` property of the parent form's `BindingSource`, and set the same property on the `BindingSource` of the details form. This worked just fine until I started sorting the `DataGridView` - now the parent's position is showing the sorted value, and all hell breaks loose.
I then tried sending in the actual `DataRow` and even the `DataRowView` object of the parent `BindingSource`, and using the `Find` method on the details `BindingSource` - but they all just return -1.
What other way I can use to set the `BindingSource` `Current` property, if I can't relay on indexes or on values? Do I have to use the `Filter` method and construct a filter query dynamically (I have multiple properties for PK, so I can't just use `Find`)?

Comment: The Find method can only be used when the underlying list is an IBindingList with searching implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through DataRows in BindingSource to find selected one.

Comment: Yeah - quite simply the simplest solution. Though I am surprised there is no easier way to sync two BindingSources that way